# How to fix jtable rendering always only (and at least) 4 rows?

Tags: java, jtable, rendering

My program should translate the pairs of key/value of a table to a escaped JSON for shell execution. This JTable is inside a JSplitPane, but only 4 rows are displayed and when there is less than 4 a white background appears where the other 1-3 rows should be. (There are more than 4 registers)
e.g.:

With data:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwhzY.png]

Without data:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu5Wt.png]
As you can see the JSON on the bottom has all the table data, but the JTable is not rendering it right. Table filling code:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = ((DefaultTableModel) tblParameters.getModel());
dtm.setRowCount(0);

currentFileParameters = (ReplacerLinkedHashMap<String, String>) FileParametersDAO.getInstance().getParametersForFile(file); // get parameters from database for specific file

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : currentFileParameters.entrySet()) {
    dtm.addRow(new Object[]{entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()}); // add row
}

dtm.addRow(new Object[]{"", ""}); // add blank row for adding more parameters
tblParameters.revalidate(); // failure trying to resolve the problem [part 1]
tblParameters.repaint(); // failure trying to resolve the problem [part 2]
LocalProperties.setLastAccessedFile(file); // saves the accessed file
loadSavedFiles(); // load all saved files to other table (that has the same problem)
```

Table was working before and stopped suddenly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Table was working before and stopped suddenly.`  - We can't guess what you changed. Either your code changed or the data change. You need to do some debugging to determine what changed and then fix it.. Start by hardcode the data in the table model so it displays properly to show you know the basics of using a JTable. Once that works, then you do your parsing of the data. If it doesn't work then you know your parsing is the problem. We have no idea what the data from your database looks like.

Comment: It stopped working after wraping it on a JSplitPane, but I changed the position of it back to outside of the JSplitPane and it stayed like that.

Comment: Like I said the problem is with your code. We can't possibly guess what you are doing. Create a JTable with hard coded data and add the table to the viewport of a JScrollPane and add the scroll pane to a panel. This is basic usage of a JTable first get the basic usage working. If it doesn't work then post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. There is nothing special you need to do. Just add data to the model and the table will repaint itself. Maybe somewhere you hardcoded a preferred size of the table?

Comment: The problem was the preferred size. Thank you for the help and sorry for the inconvenience.